Set object property values based on another property instance to support save and undo operations
I have two instances of a class where I want to replace all values in one instance with those of another instance to implement save or undo functionality.
In the following example selectedMessage contains the original values and selectedMessageTemp contains the modified values. I want to update to the values contained in selectedMessage if the save button is pressed and keep the existing record if cancel is pressed or the database save operation is not successful (selectedMessageTemp is a MemberwiseClone() of selectedMessage)
This would be the easiest way except selectedMessage is not updated with the changed values as expected:
selectedMessage = selectedMessageTemp;

This does work and causes selectedMessage to be updated with the changed values but would involve listing every field which could be long and error prone:
selectedMessage.Subject = selectedMessageTemp?.Subject;

Based on the fact this second approach works I am trying to do iterate through the fields without having to explicitly list each property as above except selectedMessage is not updated with the changed values but there are no errors being returned.
PropertyInfo[]? properties = selectedMessageTemp?.GetType().GetProperties();
if (properties != null)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        // Get the name and value of each property
        string? propertyName = property.Name;
        object? propertyValue = property.GetValue(selectedMessageTemp);

        selectedMessage?.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.SetValue(selectedMessageTemp, propertyValue);
    }
}

Where might I be going wrong?
To add some context as to why I am doing this, I have a Blazor WASM QuickGrid that shows the list of records:

Then if the user opens a record without the solution I added below any changes to the record are instantly reflected in the grid behind so whilst the form has save and cancel buttons, whilst cancel does not update the database it leaves the record looking like it was changed in the grid so I need cancel to revert it back:

What I am now doing is cloning the object to the temp one when the edit form is opened, targeting the temp object for the form and then after confirming the remote API database save was successful, setting the main object properties to the temp properties. So this way the grid is not changed so cancel can just close the form now.
P.S. I have edited my question to make it clearer which is the temp instance by adding temp to the end as not sure why this is getting downvoted.

In what way does selectedMessage = _selectedMessage; not work? They are now the same object, so will have the same property values.

When I say it doesn't work I mean it doesn't work for my purpose because I want to retain the old values so when values are changed on an edit form such as editing a customer I want to offer the user the choice of Save or Cancel where save would retain the changed values and cancel would discard them. With a MemberwiseClone() I can update each property value individually back to what it was but for model with lots of fields this would be a lot of code and I might miss a field over time so was wanting to find a better way.

Ah, I think I see what's happening now. You pass in selectedMessage from somewhere else, it's passed as a reference. You're changing the properties on the object, the caller is relying on the object reference staying the same. It would be better design to return the updated object to the caller. That way it works whether you pass back the clone or the original with changes. It's also cleaner code to return something from a function rather than altering the things that are passed as parameters.

Yes this would be better but as the edit button only has the ID of the record and uses this to load a temp object and show/hide a Bootstrap dialog I can't see how I could do this with that approach and any attempt to set an instance to a different copy of the instance doesn't update it but looping the properties using the CopyProperties function I posted in my answer does. Perhaps this is something specific to Blazor WASM projects.

Please could people let me know why they are downvoting this question so I can improve it some more. I can't think what could be added to it to make it any clearer. I put hours of research into it and provided the code I had up to the point and then solved it and returned and posted the answer in full. Whilst it may not be the perfect solution it works for me and I cannot find a solution that works anywhere else.

There are a couple of things you can do here. The first is to return the message to the caller.
public Message GetUpdatedMessage(Message message)
{
    var original = message.Clone();
    var buttonPressed = RunUserForm(message);
    if (buttonPressed == CancelButton)
        message = original;
    return message;
}

On the line message = original the reference held in message is changed, but the caller still has the original object reference. If you return the reference, the caller gets the correct object regardless of whether it's the original with updates or the clone:
selectedMessage = GetUpdatedMessage(selectedMessage);

The second thing you could do is to make the Message type a struct rather than a class. That way you can copy with simple assignment instead of cloning.

Thanks @iakobski this seems like a good approach and a cleaner way to do it to avoid the copying of properties although I can't quite work out how to restructure the code. Currently clicking on an edit button in the Blazor QuickGrid passes the ID of the item to the EditMessage function which sets selectedMessage to that record and _selectedMessage as a clone and opens a Bootstrap Dialog that takes no parameters with an EditForm referencing the clone then if the save button is pressed this runs a function that sets the original message to the cloned message if the save was successful.

I tried this again and for some reason in Blazor WASM projects setting the instance to the cloned instance does not update it but using the CopyProperties function I wrote in my answer to loop through the object and set each property value does. Perhaps it is a bug or something as it does seem strange behaviour and I can replicate this with a new blank project too.

I have finally solved this after a few hours of trying various techniques where lots of the deep clone examples seem the same as the shallow clone examples.
First I added these extension functions in a separate static class:
public static T? Clone<T>(this T obj)
{
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
}

public static void CopyProperties<T>(this T source, T target)
{
    if (source == null || target == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Source or/and Target is null");

    var type = typeof(T);
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.CanWrite)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(source);
            property.SetValue(target, value);
        }
    }
}

Then in the main code I clone the instance with this:
if (selectedMessage != null)
    selectedMessageTemp = selectedMessage?.Clone();

And restore it back with this:
if (selectedMessage != null && selectedMessageTemp != null)
    selectedMessageTemp.CopyProperties(selectedMessage);

This does what I was hoping in testing and I have added a check for if properties are writable. It would be interesting to know if there is a simpler way to do this but if there is I couldn't find it!

of course there is simpler way selectedMessage = _selectedMessage.Copy()...There is no need to copy properties manually

That doesn't compile for me as it can't find a Copy() function. The error is 'MessageModel' does not contain a definition for 'Copy' and no accessible extension method 'Copy' accepting a first argument of type 'MessageModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).. This is a Blazor WASM project in case it makes any difference.

I suggest editing your question and including all debugging details from the comments

I'm not sure why you downvoted my question and my answer and removed your own answer or what extra info you want me to add. The code I added solves it for me and I added it in full with an explanation. Whilst it may not be the best way, it's the only way I have found that works after hours of research into solving this myself. I can see this question asked a few times on here without answers that satisfy the question. I'm happy to improve my question and/or answer if you can clarify to avoid a downvote but asking me to include all debugging details when it compiles and works seems a bit vague.

I'm still confused why you need to do it like this. What does your class look like that you are cloning/copying the properties? In what way does does the assignment I asked about above not work?

I have just responded to your comment above. The issue is that I want to retain both old and new values to offer a save and cancel option on an edit form but setting one instance to the other still gave the updated rather than original values whereas setting individual property values did provide the original values. This doesn't really make much sense to me but I used that approach to build the property iterator which did the job and copied all properties including those of child entities.
